# PHPMailer has problems sending an attachment with GoDaddy

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm currently developing a web page, the site is hosted on GoDaddy and has a contact form. Sometimes I send an email with an attachment that is more than 1 mb (sometimes even less) I've got this error:

> The following From address failed: webpage@mydomain.com : Called MAIL FROM without being connected,,,,SMTP server error: Called MAIL FROM without being connected.

I discovered that this error is intermittent, while I was writing this I tried to recreate it but it didn't occur.

I appreciate your advice.

This is my current code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require '../PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require '../PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
    $mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);

    try{
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'localhost';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
        $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
        $mail->Port = 25;

        $mail->setFrom('webpage@mydomain.com', 'Web Page');
        $mail->addAddress('contact@mydomain.com', 'Contact');
        $mail->Subject = 'Web Message';
        $mail->Body = 'Name: '.$_POST['name'].PHP_EOL.
                      'Email: '.$_POST['email'].PHP_EOL.
                      'Phone: '.$_POST['phone'].PHP_EOL.
                      'Message: '.$_POST['message'];

        /* Set Attachment*/
        if( isset($_FILES["file"])){
            $file_tmp  = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $mail->AddAttachment($file_tmp, $file_name);
        }

        if($mail->send()){
            echo '1';
        }else{
            echo '0';
        }

    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Error:';
        echo $e->errorMessage();

} catch (\Exception $e){
    echo 'Error:';
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like your code is incomplete, or maybe a copy-paste error here on SO? 2x `catch` blocks but only 1 `try`?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your script. Your local mail server has a problem, which will appear in its error logs. Since you're on GoDaddy, this is a shared server and you have no control over the mail server. I suggest you contact GoDaddy support, or use a better hosting provider.

One unrelated issue: your file upload handling is not safe. Follow [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) for how to handle uploads safely, specifically, you should use `is_uploaded_file` or `move_uploaded file` rather than trusting what is in `$_FILES` directly.